# Adding to multiple tables in rails using one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Basically I'm adding books to a database, and I want to store the Author in a separate table. So I have a table called authors which is referenced by the table books.

I want to create a rails form for adding a book, and I'd like it to be just a simple form for Author, Title, Publisher etc, and if it finds the author already in the authors table then it should just reference that record, and if it isn't in the authors table then it should add a new record and reference it.

It is working but values are not storing into authors table?
and while checking the author name in the table i am getting nil Parameters:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",       "authenticity_token"=>"/Tk87vLoJx+/EgPGVEa7x59IeGMGLikknBMcMTw90oo=",   "book"=>{"book_name"=>"y", "price"=>"1", "authors"=>{"author_name"=>"b",  "title"=>"k", "publisher"=>"s"}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
        Author Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors"  WHERE   "authors"."author_name" IS NULL LIMIT 1
 Unpermitted parameters: authors

  params[:authors_name] in method Author.find_or_create_by() value is nil
 but book column values are added to books table and author table id is only apears in author table
```

creating model with reference

```
    rails generate model Author author_name:string{15} title:string{15} publisher:string{15}
    rails generate model Book book_name:string{15} price:integer Author:references
```

books-Controller

```
        class BooksController < ApplicationController
          def new

          end
         def create 
          # Client.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Andy')
           @author = Author.find_or_create_by(:author_name =>     params[:author_name]) 
           @book = Book.new(books_params)
           @book.Author = @author
           @book.save
          redirect_to root_url

         end
        private

          def books_params
             params.require(:book).permit(:book_name, :price,:address => [:author_name, :title, :publisher])
        end
        end
```

Model code

```
        class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
          belongs_to :Author
          accepts_nested_attributes_for :Author
        end

      class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
      end
```

book.html

```
<%= form_for Book.new  do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :book_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :book_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :authors do |b| %>
     <p>
    <%= b.label :author_name%><br />
    <%= b.text_field :author_name %>
  </p>
<p>
    <%= b.label :title%><br />
    <%= b.text_field :title %>
  </p>
<p>
    <%= b.label :publisher%><br />
    <%= b.text_field :publisher%>
  </p>

  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
~
```

my problem is

1. when entered author_name in testbox while accesing this  author name using parama[:authors_name] in  find_or_create By method it gives nil in the query ?

2  how to save authors columns values in authors table?

Comment: Your code has lot of errors.

Comment: sir can you please tell me the errors because i am new to rails